# Decode hierarchical data structure using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe with a sample hierarchical data as below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Level': ['0','1','2','2','3','2','3','1','2','3','3','4'],
                   'Type': ['P','U','D','I','D','PR','D','U','U','D','PR','D'],
                   'ID': ['P1','U1','D1','I1','D2','PR1','D3','U4','U8','DB1','PR3','DF1'],
                   'Value': ['','1', '0','1','0','1','0','1','1','0','1','0']
                  }
                )
df1
```

I would like to create a one-one mapping based on the column 'Level' which will be used as a root to build another dataframe like 0->1->2->3.

'Level' column should be considered to define the Parent and Child relation, for any level other than 1, the immediate previous level is the parent.

Expected output for the sample data is below

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID1': ['P','P','U1','U1','I1','PR1','U4','U8','U8','PR3'],
                   'ID2': ['U1','U4','D1','I1','D2','D3','U8','DB1','PR3','DF1'],
                    'Value':['1','1','0','1','0','0','1','0','1','0']
                  }
                )
df2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've understood your problem well:

```py
df1["Level"] = df1["Level"].astype(int)

all_data, tmp = [], {}
for lvl, id_, val in zip(df1.Level, df1.ID, df1.Value):
    if lvl == 0:
        tmp.setdefault(lvl, []).append(id_)
    else:
        parent = tmp.get(lvl - 1, [None])[-1]
        all_data.append((lvl, parent, id_, val))
        tmp.setdefault(lvl, []).append(id_)


out = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Level", "ID1", "ID2", "Value"]).sort_values(
    by="Level"
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
    Level  ID1  ID2 Value
0       1   P1   U1     1
6       1   P1   U4     1
1       2   U1   D1     0
2       2   U1   I1     1
4       2   U1  PR1     1
7       2   U4   U8     1
3       3   I1   D2     0
5       3  PR1   D3     0
8       3   U8  DB1     0
9       3   U8  PR3     1
10      4  PR3  DF1     0
```